# Combining two regex in input restriction "pattern"

Tags: html, regex, input-field

I need to have an input field where the user can only enter 7 numbers, nothing more, nothing less, nothing else.

I need (check for 7 characters)

```
pattern=".{7,7}"
```

and (check for only numbers)

```
pattern="\d*"
```

working together, but you can't define pattern two times, how would I combine these two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern="\d{7}"
```

or with explicit anchors:

```
pattern="^\d{7}$"
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bsSz5d/1).

You do not need to specify identical values for the minimum and maximum  thresholds. In case you want to allow 1 to 7 digits, then it makes sense: `pattern="\d{1,7}"`.

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: navy;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text" pattern="\d{7}" title="7 digits only!" required/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

To make the input field obligatory, add the `required` attribute.

Comment: One more question: if you input nothing, the form still sends, what can I add to stop this?

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven: Use the `required` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 pattern="[0-9]{7}"
```